# Cannot accept invitation to realm due to "incorrect privacy and online safety settings"

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I am experiencing a problem where I am unable to accept an invitation to a friend's Realm on **Minecraft for Windows 10**.

Whenever I attempt to accept the invitation, I get the message

```
You cannot play online multiplayer through Xbox
Live because of how your account is set up. This
can be changed in your privacy & online safety
settings on Xbox.com
```

I have checked through my Privacy & Online Safety settings, and have verified that my `Join multiplayer games` option is, in fact, set to `Allowed`. Despite this, I am still unable to accept the invitation.

Comment: Have you tried restarting>?

Comment: I've restarted Minecraft, I've restarted my PC… I've done this lots of times now. It lets me connect to someone else's world, but not realms.

Comment: Have you tried using different versions of minecraft? Or maybe its something with your friend's realm.

Comment: One of my other friends has been able to access the realm just fine, so it's probably not that. I am unable to purchase and download other versions of Minecraft: Bedrock Edition, meaning that Minecraft for Windows 10 is the only version I can test this on.

Comment: Thats some good information... I may have an answer for you by the end of today, I now have a good idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I have this happen to me many times and most of the times that this happens to me isn't permanent

- my First workaround: just closing Minecraft and then making sure that my internet is on and I am connected (By doing a simple google search of Hello or something)
  and then re-entering Minecraft.

if this doesn't work then I'll do my second workaround:

- restarting my device

if both workarounds fail then I'll do my third workaround:

- Singing out of Xbox live then Signing back in

if all workarounds fail then I have no more methods to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/games_windows_10/cant-play-minecraft-windows-10-edition-online/77ee06ee-02a5-4662-96f8-eacfb5d78ab6) post.
From what I can tell, it seems (to me) that the account you're trying to sign in on is a child account.

Steps for changing the birthdate is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12411/microsoft-account-change-birthdate).

Comment: The account in question is an adult account (I verified this just now), and having also read the post linked it appears that the issue is occurring on a great deal many more *adult* accounts than *child* accounts (with child accounts having been confirmed to be able to connect while adult ones for some reason cannot).